# which is the better convention for REST API URL

Tags: api, rest

I am new to REST API, and I am designing my own REST API for my web project.

Which of the followings is the better convention?

I want to access to the article that user ID 3 wrote.

```
/user/3/article
```

```
/article?user_id=3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which of the followings is the better convention?

They are both *fine*.

`/article?user_id=3` may prove more convenient if you are expecting to use HTML forms as a way of finding resources.

`/user/3/article` may prove more convenient if you expecting to use dot segments to describe other resource identifiers in the hierarchy.

---

> What if I want to access to the fourth article that User ID3 wrote? `/user/3/article/4` is appropriate? I think this hierarchy is unnecessarily deep.

Deep hierarchies are fine.  Not using deep hierarchies are also fine.

In some designs, we'll use resource identifiers for [items](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573.html#section-2.1) that are not part of the same hierarchy as the [collection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573.html#section-2.2) itself

```
context="/user/3/article" rel="item" href="/articles/4"
context="/user/3/article" rel="item" href="/articles/9"
context="/user/3/article" rel="item" href="/articles/16"
```

Think "web page with links"; if you can follow a link, you don't need a formula to compute the URI yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Then What if I want to access to the fourth article that User ID3 wrote?  ``` /user/3/article/4 ``` is appropriate? I think this hierarchy is unnecessarily deep.

Comment: @JungHwanPark A link is a link, no matter what. Clients aren't interested in a hierarchy structure, they are interested in the content they get served by requesting some URI. To hint a client on the purpose of a link certain link-relations are used and more or less attached to that URI (or vice versa), which should be [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or at least follow the common [Web linking extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288.html#section-2.1.2) approach.